# Is there a word meaning "append", but at the beginning, not the end?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, antonyms, computing

In computer programming, when you append a "string" to another, you add it to the end of the former string.

E.g.

```
String string1 = "abcd";
String string2 = "efgh";
```

Appending the two strings would give

```
"abcdefgh"
```

But what if I wanted to add string2 before string1 to have the result:

```
"efghabcd"
```

What would be a good *name* for that that reverse operation? What is the opposite of "append"?

Comment: Given you have over 1500 rep on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1199882/codeblue), I find it odd you're not familiar with **prepend**. Apart from anything else, I see it in function documentation all over the place. I think it's General Reference for any who might need to know it.

Comment: You concatenate two strings and append/prepend one string to another.

Comment: You don’t add strings; you concatenate them.

Comment: Isn't the opposite of append (adding something to a string) trim (removing something from a string)?

Comment: If you want to add the string precedent to the other then interchange the strings identifiers like `a.append(b)` to `b.append(a)`. Now `b` will prepend `a`. No need for the opposite of *append*.

Comment: Voting to close General Reference: question was "definitively and permanently answered by a single link to a standard internet reference source designed specifically to find that type of information".

Comment: @FumbleFingers You're assuming CodeBlue is a native English speaker.  There's nothing in his/her profile to indicate if that's true either way.

Comment: @ΜετάEd, except as ЯegDwight noted in a comment on his answer, there's a bit of "can't get there from here": you can't look up "append" in a thesaurus and get "prepend" out of it, and if you don't know that the word "prepend" *exists*, you can't look it up in the dictionary.

Comment: *Prepend* is the second result of the search `[ opposite of append ]`. With the word in hand, one can easily look it up.

Comment: @Dan Neely: I make no such assumption. The reason I'd expect OP to be familiar with *prepend* is because it's commonly used in programming. Whatever his native language, most **computer** documentation, library function names, etc., tend to be in English. If you do programming yourself, you'll probably know that programmers usually use *prefix/postfix* rather than the grammarian's *prefix/suffix*, for example. Programmers like things to be logical.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - "you'll probably know that programmers usually use prefix/postfix rather than the grammarian's prefix/suffix, for example. __Programmers like things to be logical__" - SO agree with this point!

Answer (score 63, accepted):

[*Prepend*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prepend):

> (*computing, linguistics, transitive*) To attach (an expression, phrase, etc.) to another, as a prefix.

Comment: I'm always too slow on the draw for these general reference questions. I need to make a script that nicely formats the definition by just putting a dictionary link in my answer. No additional copy/paste required. :(

Comment: @Zairja I actually took my time to browse thesaurus.com first. All it had on offer was "disjoin, subtract, take away". Looks like they haven't caught up on the latest lingo.

Comment: *Prepend* was the first thing I thought of.  Where was I an hour ago?

Comment: Funny, to me opposite of *append* is *shorten* or *truncate* or *remove* or *chop* or something.  It’s like how the opposite of Perl’s `pop` is more generally held to be `push` than it is to be `shift`.

Comment: @tchrist but isn't that generally true for programmers :P? We push things onto the stack, and then pop them off of it.

Answer (score 13):

[*Prepend*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prepend): To attach (an expression, phrase, etc.) to another, as a prefix

I would also consider using [*concatenate*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/concatenate), since this is often used to describe joining two strings together (and many computer languages have some kind of native `CONCATENATE` function).

Although the order of appending is implied by the order the strings are listed in, one can make it explicit by writing "append `X` to `Y`", which would result in `YX`.

If you wanted to describe the "reverse operation", you could simply reverse the order of variables in your sentence: "I'd like to append `string1` to `string2`" (resulting in `efghabcd`).

Comment: so: prepend and postpend are the two types of append?

Comment: @GEdgar *Postponing* is not the same as *appending*. *Append* means to add on (like a suffix, or writing additional data to a file). *Prepend* means to add on at the beginning like a prefix. You could use *concatenate*, as well.

Comment: @GEdgar: There was a word *prepend* long ago, nothing to do with computer neologism *prepend* - causing some to extrapolate *postpend* (to match other computery words like *pre-increment, post-increment*). But *append* has always implied *add at the end of*.

Comment: *prepend*: "... to add or append (a character, string, file, etc.) at the front of an existing string, file, etc." (OED)

Comment: `concatenate` generally refers to more than 2 strings as in `concatenate "ab", "cd" and "ef" resulting in "abcdef"` so it's not quite equivalent to `prepend` which implies only 2 strings/phrases.

Comment: @starNamer- concatenate does not imply more than two strings.  [see here for example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation) you can certainly concatenate multiple strings easily but each one adds to the result of the previous binary operation

Answer (score 1):

Both dot-net and Java StringBuilder libraries, and probably comparable things in other libraries, have an "insert" function that allows you to insert a new string at an arbitrary place in a target string. Location zero would be at the beginning, location 1 is after the first character, etc.

Thus, my practical answer to your question in a programming context is that the opposite of "append" is "insert(0)".

Note that insert is useful to insert at any known offset into a string. It is not so useful for inserting at the end of the string because we then need an extra step to find just where the end is. As this is an extremely common thing to want to do, it makes sense to have a separate append function.

In general English, we say "prepend", as others have noted. But I don't think most string-builder-type objects have a prepend function, as it would be rather redundant with insert.

Comment: Psh, kids today are so spoiled. `cons` is all you ever need for anything (and is not a bad answer here, methinks).

Comment: `insert`?  Bah.  Just `splice`.  But the opposite of appending something to the end is removing something from the end.  Also, many sequences are optimized for adding or removing at either end.

Comment: @Rachel - You've got to be cdr-ing.

Comment: @tchrist Sure, many words could have different antonyms depending on the sense in which you mean "opposite". Like what is the opposite of "man"? You could say "woman", "boy", "animal", "machine", and probably many other words, in one sense or another.

Comment: Or *unman*, the verb.

Comment: Or "mouse", as in, "What are you, a man or a mouse?" Or on Linux, "info", as in "man pages" versus "info pages". We could play this game all day!

Answer (score 0):

Prepend, insert, pre-attach. Some programming languages have additional functions that can add strings in various positions, including the start of another string. For example: slice, push, at.