# Noun for something that has been "appended"

Tags: single-word-requests

I have appended something to the end of something else, but I don't know the word to describe the what has been appended. Even after it is one big "something", I was wondering if there was a word that described the piece that was not always there before.

"Append" is the verb I am looking to convert.
"Appension" and "appendee" are not real words as far as I know.

Edit:
I have not considered "appendix" since it seems to imply being at the end specifically, rather than something that was added (anywhere) to something else.

@V0ight suggested *affix*, which seems by its definition to be much closer to what I had in mind!

Comment: But *appendix* is a real word, and it should be right there by *append* in the dictionary. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Would _appendix_ work in the context of taking a file and appending another piece of something to it (possibly before) and referring to it as an _appendix_? Appendix seems to mean just at the end, usually for a book, whereas it seems the definition of "append" means to add to something, but doesn't specify at the end. Do I have the wrong definition of _append_?

Comment: affix: [5. noun: something that is joined or attached](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/affix)

Comment: @FumbleFingers wouldn't "appendix" seem awkward if not used to describe additional content in a book? I'm not sure a native English speaker would pick up on the additional use with ease. I would think it odd, anyway. OP, I think "appendee" is okay. Maybe it's not a "real word", but it seems a logical construction that would parse easily. The English language is defined by how its speakers use it — not by the dictionary. I know of no other word that conveys the same meaning succinctly and obviously (though there may be one).

Comment: The two words that come to mind are: "appendix" and "appendage."  If you have an appendix and you append something to it, that something is an appendage, but an appendage needn't only be appended to an appendix.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Wiktionary at least labels the more general sense of [appendix](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/appendix) as "obsolete." Ryan, you should post something about the research you've done in your question; listing any real words you've already considered and rejected will allow people to write better answers.

Comment: @PierceDarragh: "appendee" sounds silly. Also, I think "-ee" tends to be used to refer to humans rather than inanimate objects.

Comment: @sumelic it only sounds silly because nobody's done it before! And while "-ee" definitely gets applied to humans more frequently, I don't see that rule as concrete. But you raise a valid point! Although OP seems to have found a good word through another comment.

Comment: @Ryan: Thanks for the edit! I'm confused by part of it, though. The question starts out "I have appended something to the end of something else" and then later you say "I have not considered "appendix" since it seems to imply being at the end specifically, rather than something that was added (anywhere) to something else." Why would it be a problem to use a word that implies something added to the end? That's the situation you're trying to describe, right?

Comment: You are right! I was using a particular example in my head when I started writing this question but I have multiple occurrences where things are appended all over the place, not just at where we would consider the "end" that I want to consider. (http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79323/is-there-a-word-meaning-append-but-at-the-beginning-not-the-end) I didn't realize that _append_ also implied to the end. Perhaps I do not mean _append_ or _prepend_, but something more general like _addition_.

Comment: Also try **supplement** or **supplemental material** or **supplementary material** or maybe **attachment**

Comment: Everyone is thinking too hard. The thing you've just appended is simply the most recent addition.

Comment: I don't think there's a common single word for this concept. *appendix* and *appendage* refer to things that are attached to other things, but they don't generally relate back to the specific act of appending (an arm or a leg is an appendage, but no one ever appended them unless they're prosthetics). If you need to express it, use multiple words. Or just use a pronoun to refer back to the item that was appended.

Comment: I think **annex** would work. See Merriam Webster's definition of both noun and verb: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/annex.

Comment: In your specific context, could you possibly opt to be more concrete in your naming, and call it, say, a "note," or a "list of Chinese restaurants in Columbia Maryland," or whatever it actually is, instead of seeking a generalized term?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading through all the comments I'd like to propose [***addendum***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/addendum).
Although mainly associated with publications it also serves in other area's.

> something that is added; *especially* : a section of a book that is added to the main or original text

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following alternatives:

[Appendage](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/appendage): 
a subordinate part attached to something; an auxiliary part; addition

[Edit: just realized that appendage is already suggested by Benjamin Harman in a comment]

[Adjunct](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/adjunct?s=t):
something added to another thing but not essential to it

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with "attachment?" Mathematica uses "prepend" (which actually means to mull over) to mean "attach at the beginning" and "append"(which actually means to attach anywhere) to mean "attach at the end." But this is just jargon. You can append a pearl to a necklace right in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the word "appendix". But when you include documents to an e-mail you should call them "attachments".