# What is the phrase for non-essential details added at the end of a summary?

Tags: phrase-requests

A TLDR summary is used to shorten a long detailed article. However, what if you have written a brief and concise summary, but would like to add further non-essential background details at the end?

Comment: Adding detail to the summary? No. I'd hope that when I hit the point when my summary wants to grow with more detail, I will recognize my summary is done.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Additional, non-essential details are sometimes called "addenda" and may be contained in an "annex", "appendix", etc. However, in that case the concise text wouldn't really be a "summary"; it would be the main body. So this question seems to be getting things backward, and I think that's why it isn't faring very well so far.

Comment: What's the full context? What kinds of details are being added?

Comment: *However, what if you have written a brief and concise summary, but would like to add further non-essential background details at the end?* Just resist that temptation, inessential background doesn't belong in a brief and concise summary.

Comment: I think this question might better be asked at a site for writing and writers, such as the nearby one in the Stack Exchange universe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Noun for something that has been "appended"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/336322/noun-for-something-that-has-been-appended) ('addendum')

Comment: A "P.S." is probably close to what I was thinking of. I was after a casual term like TLDR, rather than something as formal as "Addendum" or "Appendix".

Comment: For example, if I was sending an email to my new manager about the current repairs on a copier. I really only need to tell them that parts are on backorder, and when our vendor expects them to arrive and be installed. However,it would be helpful to give them some more context about the ongoing issues we are having with that copier and others around the campus.
It would feel rude if I wrote the detailed explanation and then prefaced it with a brief summary labelled "TLDR".

Answer (score 1):

We sometimes use "P.S.", the abbreviation for "postscript", for related, but inessential, information at the end of a text. You may occasionally see this in forum posts and Stack Exchange questions and answers.

This originally was used in letter writing, but it has been expanded to other informal texts.

Answer (score 0):

OED: **Addendum**

> **1.A thing that is added, typically in order to** correct, clarify, or **supplement something, esp. an item added at the end of a book, an
> appendix.**
>
> 1936 *A catalogue..by one of the leading American
> university presses, mentions, as one of the merits of a certain book,
> that it contains an invaluable addenda*. S.P.E. Tract (Society for
> Pure Eng.) No. XLV. 192

Answer (score 0):

Your question has something of the sense of the distinction between styles of presentation as being either deductive or inductive (This is different from the distinction between [deductive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deductive_reasoning) and [inductive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_reasoning) reasoning). A **deductive** presentation begins with its conclusion and then provides the justification. An **inductive** presentation, on the other hand, first lays out the facts and justification, and only then states the conclusion.

Answer (score -1):

Minor details belong at the beginning of a document, for example a report. You can call this a [preface](https://www.google.com/search?q=preface%20definition&sca_esv=566193960&sxsrf=AM9HkKlb69a7bQqfeK43hj1Pc8SVXyzMXg%3A1695020003960&ei=4_MHZdaIOrOJ9u8PueSM-AY&ved=0ahUKEwiWhuTJybOBAxWzhP0HHTkyA28Q4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=preface%20definition&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiEnByZWZhY2UgZGVmaW5pdGlvbjIGEAAYBxgeMgYQABgHGB4yBhAAGAcYHjIGEAAYBxgeMgYQABgHGB4yBhAAGAcYHjIGEAAYBxgeMgYQABgHGB4yBhAAGAcYHjIGEAAYBxgeSI4dUABY3hdwAXgAkAEAmAFToAHvA6oBATe4AQPIAQD4AQHCAgcQIxiKBRgnwgIEECMYJ8ICCBAAGIoFGJECwgIHEAAYigUYQ8ICCBAAGAcYHhgK4gMEGAAgQYgGAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-serp) (“a preliminary explanation") or a [clarification](https://www.google.com/search?q=clarification%20definition&sca_esv=566193960&sxsrf=AM9HkKmBqn-h9lElbvmVKLAsnhvDH4jV7A%3A1695019952629&ei=sPMHZcn5JaiQ9u8PgJqs-AE&oq=clarification%20defini&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiFGNsYXJpZmljYXRpb24gZGVmaW5pKgIIADIKEAAYgAQYRhj5ATIFEAAYgAQyBRAAGIAEMgYQABgWGB4yBhAAGBYYHjIGEAAYFhgeMgYQABgWGB4yBhAAGBYYHjIGEAAYFhgeMgYQABgWGB4yIRAAGIAEGEYY-QEYlwUYjAUY3QQYRhj0Axj1Axj2A9gBAUijjwFQAFjnfHABeACQAQCYAcABoAGFEKoBBDE2LjW4AQHIAQD4AQGoAgrCAgYQABgeGA_CAggQABiKBRiGA8ICBxAjGOoCGCfCAgcQLhjqAhgnwgIHECMYigUYJ8ICBBAjGCfCAggQABiKBRiRAsICCxAuGIAEGMcBGNEDwgIFEC4YgATCAgsQLhiABBjHARivAcICBxAAGIoFGEPCAgcQLhiKBRhDwgIHEAAYgAQYCsICCBAAGBYYHhgPwgIhEAAYgAQYRhj5ARiXBRiMBRjdBBhGGPQDGPUDGPYD2AEB4gMEGAAgQYgGAboGBggBEAEYEw&sclient=gws-wiz-serp) (“the action of making a statement or situation less confused and more comprehensible”.)

The document's conclusion could end with a brief summary.

<sub>Definitions provided by *Oxford Languages*</sub>