# A word with a meaning like "append" but not necessarily to the end

Tags: word-choice

I want to say "The owner information can be appended to the input string". But I don't want to limit the place of this addition to the end of string. It can happen at the beginning, among the string (for example in every other letter), or at the end.

What is the suitable word for this? In computer programming "append" fixes the place to the end and the reader may mistakenly think he cannot use other places.

I have read [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79323/is-there-a-word-meaning-append-but-at-the-beginning-not-the-end) . But by using "prepend" it just lets the place be at the beginning.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How about just *add*? "The information can be ***added*** to the input string" and we don't have to complicate things further.

Comment: The information can be added, included, mentioned, or any number of other things.

Comment: @ Robusto: Thanks for your answer. Since this is a context in which "add" is used to mean exactly with its mathematical meaning, I prefer not to use that with two different meaning. It can makes the readers confused.

Comment: @m123: What, your language doesn't overload words and operators? Get used to the fact that just about *any* word in English has multiple meanings, and that users of it are expected to switch between them with no trouble. English is not a programming language, and people recognize the difference between you talking about software and the software talking to the compiler.

Comment: It is not a mathematical context unless the owner information is an actual number. In which case you'd probably not call it owner information, but owner ID. No users at all will be confused. Absolutely everyone knows that adding water is not the same as adding seven.

Comment: @ RegDwigнt: "The owner information can be included string by another user". Is this correct?! it seems a little strange. I want to further explain a method which adds the owner information to the middle of string. Is it correct to start the discussion by the word "included, and then explain my special place?

Comment: It can be *inserted* into the input string.

Comment: @ RegDwigнt Thanks for your answer. I convert the name of the owner letter by letter to numbers (name it Mike=12 for M,8 for i, 10 for k, 4 for e), and then add this with for the string s_1,s_2,s_3, ....s_15). The result of my method is s1, s2, s3, s4+12, s5+ 8, s6+ 10, s7+ 4. But I want to first explain it generally, which can be (12, 8,10,4, s_1, S_2,...) or my case or...

Comment: @ Hellion: Thanks Hellion. "insert" seems suitable.

Comment: @Robusto: You are right but It is in a technical document. Since in a technical document, in the same paragraph we cannot use "reserved words" with multiple meaning. In any language this work is confusing.